# Add Click Handler to Material Design MDCBottomNavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift

So I am trying to do something which I believe may be pretty simple but I cannot figure it out. I am currently using the Material Design Bottom Nav Bar IOS Swift module and I am trying to add a way to switch to a new view whenever one of my tab buttons are pressed. Can anyone help me with this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

So for clarity, when the Home button is pressed I would like the button to call the HomeViewController, when the messaging button is pressed I would like the message button to call the MessageViewController

here is my code so far.

```
import UIKit
import MaterialComponents.MaterialBottomNavigation

class MyController: UIViewController
{
    let bottomNavBar = MDCBottomNavigationBar()

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        let size = bottomNavBar.sizeThatFits(view.bounds.size)
        let bottomNavBarFrame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                       y: view.bounds.height - size.height,
                                       width: size.width,
                                       height: size.height)
        bottomNavBar.frame = bottomNavBarFrame
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {


        bottomNavBar.titleVisibility = MDCBottomNavigationBarTitleVisibility(rawValue: 1)!
        bottomNavBar.alignment = MDCBottomNavigationBarAlignment(rawValue: 1)!


        let homeItem = UITabBarItem(
            title: "Home",
            image: UIImage(named: "house-color"),
            tag: 0)

        let messagesItem = UITabBarItem(
            title: "Messages",
            image: UIImage(named: "message-color"),
            tag: 0)


        bottomNavBar.items = [homeItem, messagesItem]
        bottomNavBar.selectedItem = homeItem
        
        view.addSubview(bottomNavBar)

        super.viewDidLoad()
        
       }
}
```

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to conform your `MyController` to the `MDCBottomNavigationBarDelegate` protocol, which provides you with the following methods:

```
    func bottomNavigationBar(_ bottomNavigationBar: MDCBottomNavigationBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        //Navigate to the selected view controller
    }
    
    func bottomNavigationBar(_ bottomNavigationBar: MDCBottomNavigationBar, shouldSelect item: UITabBarItem) -> Bool {
        //helpful to have this check to avoid reshowing the current view controller
        return bottomNavBar.selectedItem != item
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, can you go into a bit more detail for me? I am a bit new to Swift and still a little lost. So do I add the to my class like so


```class ViewControllerClozet: UIViewController, MDCBottomNavigationBarDelegate```

Comment: And if the above is the case then how can I simple get something to print when I click one of the bottom tab bar buttons? Also thank you for all your help thus far :)

Comment: Yes, exactly like your first comment. Try reading up on protocols and delegates, a protocol is a very useful swift object. As for your second comment, look at the first method (```didSelect item```): that method is called whenever an item on the bottom bar has been selected (either programmatically or by the user) and the second function returned ```true```. The second function is meant to determine whether or not you want to perform the navigation. So the check I included returns false if you're already on the selected item